# How to Tune my Group By Xquery Map?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Busy comparing SQLServer 2008 R2 and MarkLogic 8 with simple Person Entity.
My dataset is for both 1 Million Records/Documents. Note: Both databases are on the same machine(Localhost).

The following SQLServer Query is ready in a flash:

```
set statistics time on 

select top 10 FirstName + ' ' + LastName, count(FirstName + ' ' + LastName)
from [Person]
group by FirstName + ' ' + LastName
order by count(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) desc

set statistics time off
```

Result is:

```
Richard Petter  421
Mark Petter 404
Erik Petter 400
Arjan Petter    239
Erik Wind   237
Jordi Petter    235
Richard Hilbrink    234
Mark Dominee    234
Richard De Boer 233
Erik Bakker 233

SQL Server Execution Times:
  CPU time = 717 ms,  elapsed time = 198 ms.
```

The XQuery on MarkLogic 8 however is much slower:

```
(                               
  let $m := map:map()
  let $build :=
    for $person in collection('/collections/Persons')/Person
    let $pname := $person/concat(FirstName/text(), ' ', LastName/text())
    return map:put(
      $m, $pname, sum((
        map:get($m, $pname), 1)))
  for $pname in map:keys($m)
  order by map:get($m, $pname) descending
  return
    concat($pname, ' => ', map:get($m, $pname))
)[1 to 10]
, 
xdmp:query-meters()/qm:elapsed-time
```

Result is:

```
Richard Petter => 421
Mark Petter => 404
Erik Petter => 400
Arjan Petter => 239
Erik Wind => 237
Jordi Petter => 235
Mark Dominee => 234
Richard Hilbrink => 234
Erik Bakker => 233
Richard De Boer => 233

elapsed-time:PT42.797S
```

198 msec vs. 42 sec is in my opinion to much difference. 
The XQuery is using a map to do the Group By acording to this guide: https://blakeley.com/blogofile/archives/560/

I have 2 questions:

- Is the XQuery used in any way tuneable for beter performance?
- Is XQuery 3.0 with group by already usable on MarkLogic 8?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

As @wst said, the challenge with your current implementation is that it's loading up all the documents in order to pull out the first and last names, adding them up one by one, and then reporting on the top ten. Instead of doing that, you'll want to make use of indexes.

Let's assume that you have string range indexes set up on FirstName and LastName. In that case, you could run this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

for $co in 
  cts:element-value-co-occurrences(
    xs:QName("FirstName"), 
    xs:QName("LastName"), 
    ("frequency-order", "limit=10"))
return
  $co/cts:value[1] || ' ' || $co/cts:value[2] || ' => ' || cts:frequency($co)
```

This uses indexes to find First and Last names in the same document. cts:frequency indicates how often that co-occurrence happens. This is all index driven, so it will be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

First, yes, there are many ways to tune queries in MarkLogic. One obvious way is using range indexes; however, I would highly recommend reading their documentation on the subject first:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance

For a higher level look at the database architecture, there is a whitepaper called Inside Marklogic Server that explains the design extensively:

https://developer.marklogic.com/inside-marklogic

Regarding `group by`, maybe someone from MarkLogic would like to comment officially, but as I understand it their position is that it's not possible to build a universally high-performing `group by`, so they choose not to implement it.  This puts the responsibility on the developer to understand best practices for writing fast queries.

In your example specifically, it's highly unlikely that Mike Blakeley's map-based group by pattern is the issue. There are several different ways to profile queries in ML, and any of those should lead you to any hot spots. My guess would be that IO overhead to get the `Person` data is the problem. One common way to solve this is to configure range indexes for `FirstName` and `LastName`, and use `cts:value-tuples` to query them simultaneously from range indexes, which will avoid going to disk for every document not in the cache.

Comment: Also, for more sophisticated group by queries, you might want to take at this library, written for MarkLogic https://github.com/joemfb/group-by

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are relevant.  But from what you are asking for, David C's answer is closest to what you appear to want.  However, this answer assumes that you need to find the combination of first-name and last-name.

If your document had an identifying, uniq field (think primary key), then:

1. - put a range index on that field
2. - Use cts:element-values 
     --- options: (fragment-frequency, frequency-order, eager, concurrent, limit=10)
3. -The count comes from cts:frequencies
4. -Then use the resulting 10 IDs to grab the Name Information

If the unique ID field can be an integer, then the speeds are many times faster for the initial search as well.

And.. Its also possible to use my step 1-2 to get the list of Id essentially instantly and use these as a limiter on David C's answer  - using an element-value-range-query on the IDs in the 'query' option.  This stops you from having to build the name yourself as in my option and may speed up David C's approach.

Moral of the story - without first tuning your database for performance(indexes) and using specific queries (range queries, co-occurrence, etc), then the results have no chance of making any sense.

Moral of the story - part 2: lots of approaches - all relevant and viable. Subtle differences - all depending on your specific data.

The doc is listed below

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values